# Cryengine 5.4 commands

Tags: cryengine

I wanted to cap FPS in cryengine. I was advised to use commands `r_Vsync 0` and `sys_maxfps 30` (I could make a mistake, but in console I used the correct ones), but FPS is still over 360. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit the framerate in the exported game (GameLauncher), you have to enter these two commands in order

- `r_VSync = 0`
- `sys_MaxFps = 60` (if you want to cap it to 60 fps)

Unfortunately is not possible to limit your fps in the editor because of a [design choice](https://github.com/CRYTEK/CRYENGINE/issues/44#issuecomment-276098393). If you really want to limit them, you could check [this out](https://github.com/CRYTEK/CRYENGINE/pull/50), though you would have to recompile the engine.

[Here](http://docs.cryengine.com/display/CRYAUTOGEN/Home) you can also find a complete list of all the console commands with their possible values and effects.

I hope I helped you :)